# Magento index management

Tags: index

When I add a product in my shop magento it does not display. I am compelled to re-index to see my product. Yet in the indexes management they are all updated backup.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Alizée

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons behind this issue.

1. Check whether the product is assigned to an active category
2. Check whether the product has been assigned to a website
3. Check whether the product is out of stock
4. If any of the above is not the issue, re-index all and clear the cache as well

Comment: Cache is activated and clear, when i clear it, no change. My product is assigned to an active category, assigned to a website, in stock. I don't want re-index all the time when i add product...

Comment: If you don't re-index new products won't be searchable. sometimes won't show in frontend even. If you want to get rid of this, create cron job or call an observer function at the event `catalog_product_save_after`

Comment: ok thanks and how can i used it ?

Comment: so a reindex helped to show the product?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Index Management and check the update on save setting is on.

Few more things you can check for default as well as for store view scopes -:

- Product is not disabled
- Product visibility is set to "catalog, search" or "catalog"
- Product is assigned to a category
- Product is assigned to the website
- Product stock status is set to in stock
- Product qty is more than 0

Hope it helps

Cheers
S